# How to call a Fragment from CustomView

Tags: android, fragment, android-custom-view

I created a Custom EditTextView and I want to call a Fragment when Custom EditTextView has focused.

I write a code like this, but I have got a error when call fragment.

**if (someone has a good idea to call Fragment from custom View){please teach me();}**

this is my code:

```
public class OriginalEditText extends EditText {

    public OriginalEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public OriginalEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setText("");
        setHint("it is original");

        setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    // ////////////////////////////////////////////
                    // /I want to Call Fragment here. ////////////
                    // //////////////////////////////////////////
                    Fragment fgm = null;
                    testFragment testFragment=new testFragment();
                    FragmentManager manager=fgm.getFragmentManager();//null pointerException occurred here
                    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();

                    transaction.add(R.id.originalEditText1,testFragment, "test" );
                    transaction.commit();
                    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    // /but above code not work.....How to call Fragment from CustomView ////////////
                    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                }

            }
        });

    }

    public OriginalEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set fgm to null on two lines above. Obviously, you will get a null pointer exception when you write fgm.getFragmentManager(). I suggest you to set onFocusListener of your custom view inside activity/fragment.

In order to provide communication between activity and fragments, you can follow this link:
[link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your problem may come from your understanding of `FragmentManager`.
In the reference docs [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) is described as "Interface for interacting with Fragment objects inside of an Activity".

In your code, you provide your `OnFocusChangeListener` as an anonymous inner class, and create a `Fragment` called `fgm` which you set to `null`. So when you call fgm.getFragmentManager(), you are effectively trying to get the `FragmentManager` of a `Fragment` that has not yet been assigned to an `Activity`.

What you could do is make sure you pass an `Activity` as the `Context` whenever you create an instance of your custom edit text. You can then use the reference to that `Activity` to obtain the FragmentManager.

```
public class OriginalEditText extends EditText {

    private Activity mActivity;

    public OriginalEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        castContextAsActivity(context);
    }

    public OriginalEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        castContextAsActivity(context);
        setText("");
        setHint("it is original");

        setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    if (mActivity != null) {
                        FragmentManager manager = mActivty.getFragmentManager();
                        ...
                        // You now have your FragmentManager and can do what you want with it.
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private castContextAsActivity(Context context) {
        try{
            // Try and cast the supplied context as an Activity
            mActivity = (Activity) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // If we've caught an exception, then the supplied context was not an Activity.
            Log.e("OriginalEditText", "Error: You must supply an Activity as the Context!");
        }        
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Happy to help. I see you are relatively new to StackOverflow. If an answer is helpful, up-vote it. If an answer is correct, mark it as accepted (green tick).